Improper Integral of the Dirac Delta Function
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x\arctan(4x)\delta(4\pi x-1)dx$$
where $\delta$ is the Dirac Delta Function.
Here is my attempt below. I started by recalling the following two properties and then substitution.
$$\because \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(f(x))dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{|f'(x_0)|}\delta(x-x_0)dx $$
where $f(x_0)=0$ and that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(x-a)f(x)dx=f(a)$$
now substitute with $u=4x$
$$I=\frac{1}{16}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}u\arctan(u)\delta(\pi u-1)du$$
$$I=\frac{1}{16\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}u\arctan(u)\delta(u-\frac{1}{\pi})du=\left [ \frac{1}{16\pi}u\arctan u \right ]_{u=\frac{1}{\pi}}=\frac{1}{16\pi}\left [ \frac{1}{\pi}\arctan \left (\frac{1}{\pi}\right ) \right ]$$
Finally, we come to the result:
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x\arctan(4x)\delta(4\pi x-1)dx=\frac{1}{16 \pi^2}\arctan \left (\frac{1}{\pi}\right ) $$
Does this seem to be correct? I would appreciate any help. I've never taken an integral with the Dirac Delta equation so I'm not sure if it needs to be treated differently.

Don't put sentence fragments in equations like this. They render terribly on mobile.

The answer is correct. That said, appealing to the full $\delta(f(x))$ identity is overkill when $f(x)$ is a linear function. You can proceed more simply by using the scaling property ($\delta(cx)=\delta(x)/|c|$ for $c\neq 0$) to write $$\delta(4\pi x-1)=\frac{1}{4\pi}\delta\left(x-\frac{1}{4\pi}\right)$$
This allows immediate evaluation of the integral using the sampling property of the Dirac delta function. Alternatively, the $u$-substitution $u=4\pi x-1$ renders the delta function as $\delta(u)$ and so also allows direct evaluation.

Well, notice that you can use:
$$\int\limits_\mathbb{R}\text{y}\left(x\right)\delta\left(\text{n}x-\text{k}\right)\space\text{d}x=\frac{\displaystyle\text{y}\left(\frac{\displaystyle\text{n}}{\displaystyle\text{k}}\right)}{\displaystyle\left|\text{n}\right|}\tag1$$
So, in your case we get:
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty x\arctan\left(4x\right)\delta\left(4\pi x-1\right)\space\text{d}x=\int\limits_\mathbb{R}x\arctan\left(4x\right)\delta\left(4\pi x-1\right)\space\text{d}x=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle4\pi}{\displaystyle1}\cdot\arctan\left(4\cdot\frac{\displaystyle4\pi}{\displaystyle1}\right)}{\displaystyle\left|4\pi\right|}\tag2$$
